# Obtaining index for negative values(Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataset sdf:

```
sdf.head()
Out[65]: 
  Score
0  161
1  238
2  -53
3   83
4  171
```

Can somebody show me how to obtain the indexes for those values in Score, which are negative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `index`:

```
a = df.index[df['Score'] < 0]
print (a)
Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
```